# MySQL SUM multiple columns in same ROW

Tags: php, mysql

```
+---------------+---------+-----------------+---------+ 
| product_count | size1   | sproduct_count2 | size2
+---------------+---------+-----------------+---------+ 
|            13 | 2x4     |               5 |     2x6 
|            14 | 2x6     |               2 |     4x8 
|            15 | 2x8     |               3 |     2x8 
|            16 | 4x4     |               2 |     4x4 
|            17 | 4x8     |              15 |     4x8
+---------------+---------+-----------------+---------+
```

How do I get the total counts so the return results appear like:

```
product_count | size
           13 | 2x4
           19 | 2x6
           18 | 2x8
           18 | 4x4
           34 | 4x8
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT SUM(product_count+product_count2) AS product_count, size1 FROM UNITS GROUP BY size1
```

and it works for some rows and others it does not work for. Would CONCAT be something I need to use?

Comment: @vivek_23 From my understanding, all product counts with each different size should be added together. For instance, there's 14 of 2x6 in `product_count`/`size1`, and there's 5 of 2x6 in `sproduct_count2`/`size2`. The sum, 19, is shown in the result next to 2x6.

Comment: @slothiful Thanks, it's clear now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to aggregate on the union of the 2 columns:

```
select sum(t.product_count) product_count, t.size from (
  select product_count, size1 size from units
  union all
  select sproduct_count2, size2 from units
) t
group by t.size
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3qQAMk5G9CGhmad8sZRvbh/1).
Results:

```
| product_count | size |
| ------------- | ---- |
| 13            | 2x4  |
| 19            | 2x6  |
| 18            | 2x8  |
| 18            | 4x4  |
| 34            | 4x8  |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u1.product_count + if(u2.product_count is null,0,u2.product_count) as product_count,u1.size1 as size
from units u1
left join (select sum(sproduct_count2) as product_count,size2 
from units
group by size2) u2
on u1.size1 = u2.size2;
```

**Demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8TfoNen5toVHvy4DbBe7M6/0

- You could first sum up all counts from `sproduct_count2` with `size2` with a `group by` on `size2`.
- You could then do a `left join` on the above result with the `units` table itself with an additional `if` condition check if in case you find a `size1` not there in `size2`(in which case you could add a 0).

**Note:** This only filters values appearing in `size1`(with it's appropriate counts) looking at the query you tried (`SUM(product_count+product_count2) AS product_count, size1 FROM`)